# Using sendgrid domain authentication sends email to spam in Django

Tags: django, sendgrid, amazon-route53, django-email

I am trying to send email from my Django application. For this, I have used Twilio SendGrid service. Though my application can send the email, it ends up in spam folder. So, I have followed [this tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/) to authenticate my domain which I bought from AWS route 53. In sendgrid, the domain authentication status shows 'verified' but the emails are still sent to spam folder. I have not created any MX or TXT record in DNS setting as the tutorial says it was created automatically during domain authentication in sendgrid.

One thing I have noticed that the email still shows, 'via.sendgrid.net' message (attached an image below) with the email. Whereas it should be my authenticated domain name. I have created sendgrid account with an outlook email and using that address to send email from Django app. Is this the reason my emails are going to spam? Or can anyone please help me to find a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance.

FYI: I have done 'Single Sender Verification' in sendgrid during developing this app. But now I have deployed it in aws. I guess this feature is still working instead of 'Domain Authentication'.

[image]